# Set sms priority in android

Tags: android, sms

I want to set sms priority from a specific number. That when my broad cast receiver, receives the text message from a specific number it sets its priority to high so that the default sms notification tray shows that text message on the top of all others no matter how many text messages it receives from other numbers, unless of course my text message is read. I am able to receive text message in broad cast receiver and I am also able to get the phone number. How I can set priority, so that sms will show on top always unless it is read?

Comment: If you're talking about a `Notification` that your app is creating, then post that code. Otherwise, you have no control over how another app issues its own `Notification`s.

Comment: Yes, I want to set priority in default text message notifications.